What should the type of `req.files` with `express-busboy` be in TypeScript?
@types/express-busboy doesn't augment Request, as I expected. Documentation just says

The module will populate req.body and req.files like the body-parser module does.

But body-parser's documentation or code doesn't mention req.files.
Looking at express-busboy's own code, I see where it's initialized https://github.com/yahoo/express-busboy/blob/db8378f8d7b4eccfa8174af264e8ccb00f67f762/index.js#L72, but not where anything is added to it. https://github.com/yahoo/express-busboy/blob/db8378f8d7b4eccfa8174af264e8ccb00f67f762/index.js#L111-L113 just expects everything to be added already. So presumably it's done by connect-busboy or by busboy itself, but I failed to find anything there either.
And tests aren't much help, except for showing that it's an object with file names as keys, and values are either objects with a .file field or are an array of such objects.
